# how to use go to different branch if a string contains different words in scala using match/case?

Tags: scala, match

I have the following code using if, but is there any nicer syntax using case match?

```
val a="somestring"

if (a.contains("companyA")){
   "companyA"
}
if (a.contains("companyB")){
   "companyB"
}
if (a.contains("companyC")){
   "companyC"
}
else {
  "no company matched"
}
```

Comment: Something to note: In your code above, the original `if`s would fall through to the last if/else, so that `a="companyA"` would actually return `no company matched`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all yours companies in a List and use `find` to find your company or return "no company matched"

```
scala> val listOfCompanies = List("companyA", "companyB", "companyC")
listOfCompanies: List[String] = List(companyA, companyB, companyC)

scala> val a = "somestring"
a: String = somestring

scala> listOfCompanies find  { comp => a contains comp }  orElse Some("no company matched")
res20: Option[String] = Some(no company matched)

scala> val a = "companyB"
a: String = companyB

scala> listOfCompanies find  { comp => a contains comp }  orElse Some("no company matched")
res21: Option[String] = Some(companyB)
```

Notice that find returns the first matching element. See [here](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
val a = "somestring"

a match {
  case a if a.contains("companyA") => "companyA"
  case a if a.contains("companyB") => "companyB"
  case default => "no company matched"
}
```

Comment: That's really just different boiler plate with added "case a"'s. Can a custom extractor be used to do the "contains" test?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly nicer syntax, but not using match:

```
 def checkCompanies(c:String, cs:List[String]) = cs.collectFirst{case m  if c contains m => m}.getOrElse("no company matched")
     //> checkCompanies: (c: String, cs: List[String])String

 checkCompanies("companyA", List("companyA", "companyB"))
    //> res0: String = companyA
 checkCompanies("companyC", List("companyA", "companyB"))
    //> res1: String = no company matched
```

If the list of names is fixed, you can obviously change the def to refer to a definition in a wider scope and not pass it in each time